# Trouble with SQL trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Need help with a trigger.
If I remove my inner joins from where clause it runs, so I'm guessing this is where the issue would be. If I use this where clause it works "WHERE oeordhdr_sql.A4GLIdentity =@id "

Any help would be appreciated.  Below is the code...

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[bdordermakeonhold]
on [dbo].[oeordhdr_sql]
for insert
as
declare @edi as char(1)
declare @id as numeric(9,0)
declare @ordno as char(8)
declare @ordtype as char(1)
declare @cus_no as char(12)
declare @status as char(1)
declare @ship_to_addr_3  as char(40)
set @edi=(select edi_fg from inserted)
set @id=(select a4glidentity from inserted)
set @ordno=(select ord_no from inserted)
set @ordtype=(select ord_type from inserted)
set @cus_no=(select cus_no from inserted)
set @status=(select status from inserted)
set @ship_to_addr_3=(select status from inserted)
set nocount on
if @edi is null or @edi='E'
if not exists  (SELECT ID, Cus_No, State, CertificateID, Expiration FROM BDSalesTaxCerts     
WHERE  State = 'FL' AND @cus_no = Cus_No)

begin
UPDATE oeordhdr_sql
SET          status = 'C',hold_fg = 'H' 
FROM         inserted AS i INNER JOIN
         oeordlin_sql AS LN ON LN.ord_no = i.ord_no INNER JOIN
         ARCUSFIL_SQL as CS ON i.cus_no = CS.cus_no
WHERE        oeordhdr_sql.A4GLIdentity =@id and cs.state not in  ('FL','PR',' ','lima') and     
(LN.loc = 'SE') AND (@ship_to_addr_3 LIKE '%FL%') AND @status  in ('1') 
if not exists (select ID from BDInvoiceSupport where Orig_Ord_no=@ordno and orig_ord_type   
=@ordtype)
begin
INSERT INTO [dbo].[BDInvoiceSupport]
([ID]
,[LastUpdate]
,[RecordRevLevel]
,[Inv_No]
,[TaxProcessingStatus]
,[Orig_Ord_no]
,[orig_ord_type]
,[InvoiceSent]
,[OnHoldReason])
select NEWID(),GETDATE(),0,inv_no,0,ord_no,ord_type,0,'Not checked yet.'
from inserted
end
end
```

Comment: I think you need a semicolon between the `UPDATE` and `IF` statements.

Comment: Are you getting an error when you try to compile the trigger, or and error when the trigger executes. What error are you getting?

Comment: Triggers are designed to operate on all affected records at once. If multiple records are modified, then the inserted table will contain more than one record. In this case, the variables hold only one value, while the inserted table has many values, and could be a cause for error or failure. I would recommend not storing values from the inserted table into variables, but rather process in a set oriented manner.

Answer (score 0):

If two rows get inserted at once, this would give you problems. You should write it with joins to the `inserted` table, instead of using variables.